# Jenkins : Pycharm : I keep getting a message to upgrade pip

Tags: selenium, jenkins, pycharm

Im trying to run automated test on jenkins cloud version : so i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-0739wibs/cryptography/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    from setuptools_rust import RustExtension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'


Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0739wibs/cryptography/

You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Import chromedriver on the env variable.
Import python path on the env variable.
/tmp/jenkins3940904514869226010.sh: line 16: pytest: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I do `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

I get `Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (22.0.3)` 
`

Comment: Looks like you are running it manually inside a virtual environment, but when running threw Jenkins it is running with the main installation (outside the virtual environment) and hence the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding this line on Execute shell

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```